# Verification of the derivative of $f'(x)=\sqrt{2\pi b}\exp\left(\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it true or false that the derivative of the function $f^\prime$ given by

\begin{equation}f^{\prime}(x)=\sqrt{2\pi b}\exp\left(\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right),\qquad x\in(0,1)\end{equation}

satisfies \begin{equation}f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\frac{f(x)-a}{b}f^{\prime}(x)^2,\qquad x\in(0,1)\end{equation}
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b>0$ are constants.

I have tried the following:

\begin{align*}f^{\prime\prime}(x)&=\left[\sqrt{2\pi b}\exp\left\{\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right\}\right]^{\prime}\\&=\sqrt{2\pi b}\exp\left\{\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right\}\left[\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right]^\prime\\ &=\sqrt{2\pi b}\exp\left\{\frac{(f(x)-a)^2}{2b}\right\}\frac{2(f(x)-a)}{2b}f^{\prime}(x)\\&= \frac{f(x)-a}{b}f^{\prime}(x)^2\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the first equality.

Comment: Now you have the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is true
find second order derivative of f'(x). after simple calculations you will be able to know the answer